# jQuery: click event can't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the area and the button value by clicking the different Tabs.

Here's my question:

1. First loading the page, the button effect is working, but after clicking the other Tabs, it can't work.
2. On clicking the second Tab, then clicking the area button, you'll find it can't work.

Here's part of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var _showTab = 0;
$('ul.tabs').each(function () {
    $(this).find('li').each(function (k) {
        if (k != 0) {
            $($(this).find("a").attr("href")).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active').append("<span class='tr_icon'></span>");
        }
    })
});
$('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        _clickTab = $this.find('a').attr('href');
    $this.addClass('active').append("<span class='tr_icon'></span>").siblings('.active').removeClass('active').children().remove('span');
    // $(_clickTab).stop(false, true).fadeIn().siblings().hide();
    paidChange();
    areaChange();
    return false;
}).find('a').focus(function () {
    this.blur();
});
});
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/q79bd7bg/) all of my code:

Sorry for my poor English, and I hope you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: Try using delegate `$(document)on("click", 'ul.tabs li', function(){})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.on` click will trigger on dynamically added tabs.

Change

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() { });
```

to

```
$(document).on("click", 'ul.tabs li', function(){});
```

Comment: @Elsa, Glad to help you